# Mifare sector read-only

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard

i have a MIFARE Classic EV1, and I can't write to sector 3 because it is read only. I have already made sure that the keys are correct

[image: Sector 3 photo]

[image: Read only error photo]

Any ideas on how can I write to it?

Comment: One key should be able to change the access. Change access, write your data, change back.